# !IsPostBack Загрузка нового значения переменной

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
  public partial class Users : BasePage
{
    UsersControl UC = new UsersControl();
    protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC.AddControls();
    }
}
```

и

```
public class UsersControl : BasePage
{
    public static int TestVariable;
    public void AddControls()
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.Attributes.Add("class", "holder");

        Label CurentValue = new Label();
        CurentValue.Text = TestVariable.ToString();

        LinkButton Plus = new LinkButton();
        Plus.Attributes.Add("class", "Increment");
        Plus.Text = "+";
        Plus.Click += new EventHandler(Plus_Click);

        LinkButton Minus = new LinkButton();
        Minus.Attributes.Add("class", "Decriment");
        Minus.Text = "-";
        Minus.Click += new EventHandler(Minus_Click);

        div.Controls.Add(Minus);

        div.Controls.Add(CurentValue);

        div.Controls.Add(Plus);

        ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(div);
    }

    private void Minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TestVariable--;
        }
    }

    private void Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TestVariable++;
        }
    }
}
```

Если нажать одну из кнопок (+/-), страница перезагрузится, а новое значение в Label появиться только если еще раз обновить страницу.

Как сделать так чтобы новое значение переменной грузилось сразу после нажатия на кнопку и первой перезагрузки?

Comment: Проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку сначала отрисовывается контрол а потом только меняеться значение переменной.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону UpdatePanel
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось как-то так. Разделил прорисовку на части, и значение выводил уже после изменения переменной

aspx:

```
 protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC.RenderControls();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UC.RenderValue();
        }
    }
```

class:

```
  public class UsersControl : BasePage
  {       
    private static int TestVariable;
    private LinkButton Plus()
    {
        LinkButton Plus = new LinkButton();
        Plus.Click += Plus_Click;
        Plus.Attributes.Add("class", "action");
        Plus.Text = "+";
        return Plus;
    }

    private LinkButton Minus()
    {
        LinkButton Minus = new LinkButton();
        Minus.Click += Minus_Click;
        Minus.Attributes.Add("class", "action");
        Minus.Text = "-";
        return Minus;
    }

    private  void Minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestVariable--;
        RenderValue();
    }

    private  void Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestVariable++;
        RenderValue();
    }

    private static Label CurentValue()
    {
        Label CurentValue = new Label();
        CurentValue.Text = TestVariable.ToString();
        return CurentValue;
    }

    private HtmlGenericControl Holder()
    {
        HtmlGenericControl Holder = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        Holder.Attributes.Add("class", "holder");
        return Holder;
    }

    public void RenderControls()
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Minus());
        ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Plus());
    }

    public void RenderValue()
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(CurentValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Хотя наверно можно было просто методах Minus_Click и Plus_Click присвоить к label.text новое значение xD

Comment: Хотя нет. Так бы не получилось бы